# Nginx too many redirects when redirecting http to https

Tags: http, redirect, nginx, https

I'm trying to redirect http to https. I use letsencrypt for ssl certificates. My config looks like this

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com www.example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_timeout 5m;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        root /var/www/landing;

        location /.well-known/ {
                root /var/www/;
        }
}
```

When I'm trying to access example.com, I get a browser error saying that there were too many redirects. The error occurs for both http://example.com and https://example.com, the server block is accessed when I go to http://www.example.com because I get redirected to https://example.com and then I get the error above.

How can I fix this?

Comment: check your site content, as it might have many hardcoded http links.

Comment: I'm typing the url in the address bar of the browser and it works if I'm not doing the redirect so I think it doesn't have anything to do with the site content

Comment: without the redirect, your server listen to both port 80 for http requests and port 443 for https, there is no http url being redirect from port 80 to port 403, of course it "works"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I did `wget -S  https://wellcode.com` I assumed that the problem was on the dns so in Cloudflare I changed SSL to full and the problem was solved.

#### Explanation:

The `-S` flag will output headers and therefore show you the redirects. Example:

```
  HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
  Server: nginx
  Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2021 12:26:55 GMT
  Content-Type: text/html
  Content-Length: 162
  Connection: close
  Location: https://example.com/foo?bar=baz&dragons=probably
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: nginx
  Date: Tue, 05 Jan 2021 12:26:55 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Connection: close
  Vary: Accept-Encoding
  X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.13
  Expires: Tue, 05 Jan 2021 12:26:55 GMT
  Cache-Control: max-age=0
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains
```

Comment: Man! I just spent 3 hours on this. So grateful for stumbling onto this! :)

Comment: This is highly useful in testing against NGINX configurations and general troubleshooting beyond passing -t to NGINX. Thank you